# Assigning Combobox SelectedItem.Text a String

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, oracle10g

I am receiving the following exception when trying to assign the value from 'model' into a Combobox named ModelNumTB.

For some reason I cannot get it to copy over the value of the string into the default loading value of the Combobox.  How are you supposed to do this?
     string model;

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="ModelNumTB" runat="server" 
                    AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="ComboboxDS" 
                    DataTextField="MODEL_NUMBER" DataValueField="MODEL_NUMBER" MaxLength="0" 
                    style="display: inline;" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="ModelNumTB_SelectedIndexChanged"></ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
```

[image: Null Reference Exception]

Changing it to the following doesn't work either:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ModelNumTB.SelectedItem.Text = model;
```

to:

```
ModelNumTB.Text = model;
```

The SelectedItem property is null

Comment: I originally had that, it didn't work.  It just assigns ModelNumTB to "".  I edited the above post to show that it assigns "" to it.  'model' is populated however.

Comment: Are you sure `oString` actually has a value?  If so, perhaps the control's DropDownStyle property isn't set to "DropDown"?  That might prevent any text from being entered if there isn't a matching item.

Comment: Yeah, oString would throw an exception if there was a null value in the reader before it ever gets to assigning into ModelNumTB.Text.

Comment: That's true, but if oString has a value of "", then it would act exactly like you say it does :)